# How to truncate log file with filter?

Tags: debugging, jakarta-ee, struts2, log4j, logfile

I need some filter to truncate a lot of log information that my Java EE Application writes. I'm using Struts2.

This is my file `log4j.properties`

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = E:\\Uiip\\ProjectWork\\Workspace
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DEBUG_APPENDER
log4j.logger.OTHER_LOGGER=DEBUG, INFO_APPENDER

log4j.additivity.OTHER_LOGGER = false

#File appender for log debug
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.File=${log}/logDebug.txt

#File Appender for log info
log4j.appender.INFO_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.INFO_APPENDER.File=${log}/logInfo.txt

# Define the layout for file appender log debug
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DEBUG_APPENDER.layout.conversionPattern=%d [%t] %m%n

# Define the layout for file appender log info
log4j.appender.INFO_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.INFO_APPENDER.append=false
log4j.appender.INFO_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [%t] %m%n
```

Each time I started my app, for the login only, the logdebug file become about 1MB!

What can I use to filter my Debug logfile?

P.s. the infofile works ok!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the error level to `categorie`s, for example:

```
# This will always be printed (except TRACE level...);
log4j.category.org.apache.struts2=DEBUG

# This will be printed only in INFO or higher
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory.xml=INFO
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils = INFO

# This will be printed only in ERROR or higher
log4j.category.com.opensymphony.xwork2=ERROR
log4j.category.freemarker.beans=ERROR
log4j.category.freemarker.cache=ERROR
```

Read more on [**log levels**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Log_level)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do filtering using properties file configuration. Use xml configuration instead. The sample configuration with filters

```
<appender name="MyFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="myfile.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
        <param name="StringToMatch" value="MyStringToMatch" />
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>
```